# Get element by id from another page by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 pages `index.html` and `about.html`. In `about.html` there's a table aI need to get value from TD with `id = 'id1'` and assign it to some variable `X` to be used later at page `index.html`.

This would perfectly worked if I had it in one page.

```js
var X = document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML;
alert(X); // 123
```

```html
...
<td id='id1'>123</td>
...
```

But how to get value from `id1` from `about.html`?
I'd prefer JavaScript because I'm not so good with jQuery at the moment, but if it's not possible jQuery would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want is to store the value of `x` to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) like so:

`localStorage.setItem('someName', x);`

And then access it from yout other page like so (provided that both pages are part  of the same domain name):

`x = localStorage.getItem('someName', x);`

Comment: But how to get it without storing it in local storage?

Comment: Store it to a cookie, or store it to the server and request it when you are on your other page. You will **have** to store it somewhere that is not the runtime environment of your code, because that changes everytime you refresh or change pages.

Comment: I don't need to store it always. It just a little project. I don't care if it will change every time I load page.

Comment: Well, you need to store it, though, there is literally no other way to transfer some value from one page to another without doing so. See for yourself: open up the console and do `var test = 'test'`. Type `test` to check that it has the value you just assigned. Now refresh the page or head back to the home page of stackoverflow and open up the console again and type `test` again. See what message you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.localStorage`:

```
  localStorage.setItem('x', document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML);
```

Now on the second page you can get it:

```
 var x = localStorage.getItem('x');
 if(x){
    alert(x);
 }
```

You can send it in the url, let's say you are able to create URL like `about.HTML?x=thevalue`. Then on the about page:

```
if(location.href.index of('=') !== -1){
    var x = location.href.split('=').pop();
    alert(x);
}
```

`.split()` will create array and `.pop()` will give you the last element of the array which in this case will be `123`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax`. With jQuery it will be much easier.

So, based on using jQuery, you can use [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

**index.html**

**javascript**

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('<div />').load('/toruta #td1', function(data) {
    alert($(this).find('td').html());
  });
});
```

**html**

```
<button>show</button>
```

---

**about.html**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">loaded via ajax</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Working bin**

index like:
http://output.jsbin.com/pafehe

about like: 
http://output.jsbin.com/toruta

Comment: Can you please explain it? I'm trying, but still don't get it.
`$('#mark').click(function() {
 $('<div />').load('about.html #math', function(data) {
  alert($(this).find('td').html());
 });
});`
Here's mine code. #mark is id of button. #math is id of td element from where I must get value.

Comment: when you click on `#math` button you call `about.html` page, in the result the function looking for an element with id `math` and put the html of the element into the element who called the function - in this case the `$('<div />)` which is temporary `div`. Savvy?